# How to add vary by origin to asp.net options header

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, web

I am using cors how to enable vary by origin for options in asp.net? so the options will have vary:origin header.
Here is the code I am using

```
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(Origins,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => ListOfOrigin(origin))
                           .AllowAnyHeader()
                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                           .AllowCredentials()
                           .SetPreflightMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [resource-implementation](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-implementation):

> Resources that wish to enable themselves to be shared with multiple
> Origins but do not respond uniformly with "*" must in practice
> generate the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header dynamically in
> response to every request they wish to allow. As a consequence,
> authors of such resources should send a Vary: Origin HTTP header or
> provide other appropriate control directives to prevent caching of
> such responses, which may be inaccurate if re-used across-origins.

If a request may contain a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with different values, then the CDN should always respond with `Vary: Origin`, even for responses without an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

if the requestor doesn't provide a Origin header in their request, or an Origin value that is not one of the allowed ones, the response does not include the `Vary: Origin` in the response.